# My yu Yureka is bricked now I tried installing nougat with cm-14 but there is a error being displayed while installing cm 14 (comparing tz version)?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.4-kitkat, rooting, root-access, 7.0-nougat

[image]error 7 looks like the both the firmware's are not compatible(googled). now the only solution available online was to flash with twrp recovery which needed the phone to start which is not possible for me. 
P.S  currently i have installed  CWM recovery
i  have attached a picture or the error.

so is there any other easier solution to this problem?
can you please also mention the steps?
thanks

Comment: Ain't this obvious already? New ROMs require new base components. You need to update your stock firmware first, so that TZ can be updated as well.

Comment: no for me it isn't that's why i came here. 
so what you are saying is i can't go from cm 11 to cm 14 i need to install 12 or 13 to get to cm 14?

Comment: Not even 12 or 13, you need to flash a newer stock firmware first as a base for anything new. That's not something you can just skip.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but i am still confused.
my phone came with  cm11 and 4.4.4 kitkat 32bit. as i have understood u are saying i have to reinstall this base kit(as these files got corrupted during brick) before i do anything else.
P.S u have to understand i am not a techie. so please mention clearly as it would make things more clear for me

Comment: Well I don't own this phone myself so I can't get it down to the details, but I meant you to install the *latest* factory firmware available. For [Yureka](https://cyngn.com/support/), that's Cyanogen OS 12.1, not CM11.

Comment: thanks now i understand i was directly jumping to the last step.
last question,
now the thing is my phone is bricked means i can't start it(it was on kitkat cm 11 at that time), if it was working i would have installed the latest factory firmware as you said. so now to unbrick it i have to install cm 11 with kitkat 4.4.4 32 bit, then i would have to install Cyanogen OS 12.0(because 32bit to 64bit jump) only after that can i install Cyanogen OS 12.1, or can i directly install  Cyanogen OS 12.1 in order to unbrick it.
i read many articles online about everything so not everything is clear.

Comment: The link I gave you offers fastboot packages. With proper driver installed you should be able to flash it directly via fastboot, but it does require a PC.

Comment: I'm moving this to an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error

> Comparing TZ version TZ.BF.3.0.R2-00034 to TZ.BF.2.5.2-00005
>
> assert failed: cm.verify_trustzone("TZ.BF.3.0.R2-00034") == "1"

is quite obvious: it means this ROM requires a new version of TrustZone. You will not be able to install anything sufficiently new until you update that.

Such base components can be upgraded via flashing a factory firmware. For Yureka, the latest Cyngn offers is [Cyanogen OS 12.1](http://builds.cyngn.com/factory/tomato/cm-12.1-YOG4PAS8A4-tomato-signed-fastboot-a7a306cebd.zip). Flash it via fastboot using the guide offered on [YU's forum](http://forums.yuplaygod.com/threads/official-factory-images-and-flashing-tools-for-yureka-plus.24019/). After that, flash a custom recovery again, then finally load the custom ROM you wanted.

Additionally, I have downloaded the package and verified that it does have the TZ component inside:

[image]

... and the version is right:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, 
i was able to somehow start my phone last night by flashing it with cm11 as it was bricked, yes i could have just flashed it with cm12.1 which i understand now due to ur answer. currently i am downloading the cm12.1 and will flash my phone with it. Forgive me my knowledge about all this stuff is just 24 hrs old(i started yesterday morning). There are so many fake videos out there saying it could be done directly from cm11 which were the cause of my confusion. 
thanks again for clearing all that.